# Accessing a static variable via an object reference in Java

Tags: java, scope, static

Why can we access a static variable via an object reference in Java, like the code below?

```
public class Static {
    private static String x = "Static variable";

    public String getX() {
        return this.x;                 // Case #1
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Static member = new Static();
        System.out.println(member.x);  // Case #2
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could also do

Static.x

no need to create an object.

Comment: IIRC, Josh Bloch has said that allowing this was a bad decision.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, public variables can be accessed by everybody, and private variables can only be accessed from within the current instance of the class. In your example you're allowed to access the `x` variable from the `main` method, because that method is within the Static class.

If you're wondering why you're allowed to access it from another instance of Static class than the one you're currently in (which generally isn't allowed for private variables), it's simply because static variables don't exist on a per-instance basis, but on a per class basis. This means that the same static variable of *A* can be accessed from all instances of *A*.

If this wasn't the case, nobody would be able to access the private static variable at all, since it doesn't belong to *one* instance, but them all.

Answer (score 6):

The reason that it is allowed is that the JLS says it is.  The specific sections that allows this are [JLS 6.5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.5.2) (for the `member.x` cases) and [JLS 15.11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1) (in both cases). The latter says:

> If the field is static:
>
> - If the field is a non-blank final field, then the result is the value of the specified class variable in the class or interface that is the type of the Primary expression.
> - If the field is not final, or is a blank final and the field access occurs in a class variable initializer (§8.3.2) or static initializer (§8.7), then the result is a variable, namely, the specified class variable in the class that is the type of the Primary expression.

---

Why are these allowed by the JLS?

Frankly, I don't know.  I can't think of any good reasons to allow them.

Either way, using a reference or `this` to access a static variable is a bad idea because *most programmers* are likely to be mislead into thinking that you are using an instance field.  That is a strong reason to not use this feature of Java.

In your first and second cases you should reference the variable  as `x` or `Static.x` rather than `member.x`.  (I prefer `Static.x`.)

Comment: agree. and I want to explicitly emphasize that using `member.x` or `this.x`, although not recommend at all,  are still viable and will NOT have any compile error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  However, I don't think it needs emphasizing any more;  the accepted Answer does a good job of that. Anyway the Question is "**why** is it allowed", not "is it allowed".

Answer (score 4):

It is not best practice to reference a static variable in that way.

However your question was why is it allowed?  I would guess the answer is to that a developer can change an instance member (field or variable) to a static member without having to change all the references to that member.

This is especially true in multi-developer environments.  Otherwise your code may fail to compile just because your partner changed some instance variables to static variables.

Comment: Make an instance variable static *ought* to cause compile errors. It's a design flaw not a feature that such changes fail to ripple downstream.

Answer (score 0):

static variables are otherwise called as class variables, because they are available to each object of that class.

As member is an object of the class Static, so you can access all static as wll as non static variables of Static class through member object.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, not that there is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The non-static member is instance member. The static member(class wide) could not access instance members because, there are no way to determine which instance owns any specific non-static members.

The instance object could always refers to static members as it belongs to class which global(shared) to its instances.

Answer (score -2):

This logically makes sense although it is not interesting practice. Static variable is usually for enforcing single declaration of variable during instantiation. Object is a new copy of Class with other name. Even though object is new copy of class it is still with characteristics of the (uninstantiated) Class (first invisible instance). Therefore new object also has that static members pointing to the original copy. Thing to note is: New instance of StackOverflow is also StackOverflow.

Comment: And object is not a "copy" of a class, and there is no "pointing to the original copy".  Static fields are not actually stored in **any** instance of the class.  They are stored somewhere else.   (Where?  Implementation specific!)  Basically, you are tying to explain the JLS semantics based on an incorrect mental model of a JVM's implementation of statics.