# static members throught static methods

Tags: java

Given:

```
public class Base {
    public static final String FOO = "foo";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Base();
        Sub s = new Sub();
        System.out.print(Base.FOO);       // <- foo
        System.out.print(Sub.FOO);        // <- bar
        System.out.print(b.FOO);          // <- foo
        System.out.print(s.FOO);          // <- bar
        System.out.print(((Base)s).FOO);  // <- foo
    } 
}

class Sub extends Base {
    public static final String FOO="bar";
  }
```

My doubt is that in line 8 and line 9 we are using reference variables to access static members of class... is it possible? Because static members are accessed by class names only... Please correct me where i am wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just run the example?

Comment: `line 8`? huh, sorry, but we cannot handle your homework by this way. please edit your post

Comment: It's the opposite: instance members can only be accessed by instances, when class members may be accessed by both ways: static or instance

Comment: You can use something like http://www.compileonline.com to check things like this. Compiling it there does indeed return `foobarfoobarfoo`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going option D.

Static members are resolved at compile time using the *declared* type, not the *actual* type.

That's why `((Base)s).FOO)` refers to `Base.FOO` - even though the object is a `Sub`.

This would also occur, and is better illustrated, in the following:

```
Base b = new Sub(); // valid
System.out.print(b.FOO); // foo
```

Here `b.FOO` refers to `Base.FOO` because of the *declared* type, even though the instance is a `Sub`.

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible?

Yes it's possible, although not a good practice. Basically, accessing the static member on field is resolved at compile time as access on the declared type of the field.

For example, even the below case would work fine:

```
class Test {
    public static String hello = "Hello";
}

Test test = null;
System.out.println(test.hello);
```

The print statement will not throw `NPE`, as you would expect it on first look. Because the access is effectively resolved to:

```
Test.hello
```

Since the declared type of `test` is `Test`, the access is resolved this way.

---

Now since the static field access is resolved using the declared type at compile time, for this reason you won't see polymorphic behaviour for static methods. It goes like, you can't override static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Static members can be accessed by instances as well.

IMO it's a Bad Practice because it's misleading/uncommunicative.

In fact, you can use a `null` reference, e.g.,

```
Base base = null;
System.out.println(base.FOO);
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* access static variables via references.
But normaly you should get a warning from your compiler....

Answer (score 0):

Static variables can be accessed by class name as well as by a reference. Refer to [Access static variable from object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765445/access-static-variable-from-object-in-java)