# Sorting out few questions I am unsure about with Java

Tags: java

```
package Day4;

public class clasAndobjDemo {

    static int a = 90; //Data memeber ,Properties
    static int b = 100; // Data Memeber Poperties

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clasAndobjDemo obj1 = new clasAndobjDemo();
        obj1.sub();
        obj1.sum();
        System.out.println(obj1.a);
        System.out.println(obj1.b);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public void sub() {
        int x = 80, y = 100, z = x - y;
        System.out.println("Print" + z);
    }

    public void sum() {
        int x = 80, y = 100, z = x + y;
        System.out.println("Print" + z);
    }
}
```

Output for above code is:

> Print 20
>  Print 80
>  90
>  100
>  90
>  100

Can someone please help me to understand why I am getting:

> 90
>  100
>  90 
>   100.

Comment: Because you print `a`, then `b` (as variables of the object), then `a` again, then `b` again (this time as static variables to the class being called from a static method).

Comment: Your `sub` and `sum` methods do not change the data fields `a` and `b` in your object. Therefore, `obj1.a` and `obj2.a` are the same as `a` and `b`.

Comment: What's your question? Is it like "why you can access static member through object"? If so here's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765445/access-static-variable-from-object-in-java

Answer (score 0):

A static variable can be accessed in many ways.

Static variables can be accessed directly in both static/non-static method. 
Also, a static variable can be accessed from an object.

```
System.out.println(obj1.a);
```

However, the above method is discouraged.

Since static variables are owned by the class(only one copy for all the objects), you can access them without using instance references.

i.e.
directly(within the class itself)

```
System.out.println(a);
```

or using classname

```
clasAndobjDemo.a
```

References : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html