# make inner enum from existing enum // enum alias

Tags: java

There exists an enum

```java
public enum Direction {
  LEFT,
  RIGHT
}
```

I can access it by `Direction.LEFT`, I would also like to be able to access it by `myObject.direction.LEFT`:

```java
public class MyClass {
  public ??? direction = ???;
}

MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
assert myObject.direction.LEFT == Direction.LEFT;
```

How can I alias an enum as above, as if it were a nested inner enum?

(The reason I want this is so that I can pass `Direction` to the IL's environment via the host object `myObject` in GraalVM)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Makes no sense to me either. Far more reasonable to `assert myObject.direction == Direction.LEFT;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without doing anything special:

```
public class MyClass {
  public Direction direction;
}
```

You would be able to access `myObject.direction.LEFT`, and it would refer to exactly the same object as `Direction.LEFT`.

This is because every enum constant is a static final field ([JLS 8.9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3)), and [static fields can be accessed with or without an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765445/accessing-a-static-variable-via-an-object-reference-in-java).

But if the sole purpose of this `direction` field is to create an alias for `Direction.LEFT` and `Direction.RIGHT`, it would be quite confusing, as the purpose of a field is to *store data*.

Comment: How does this work? I am surprised it works without any assignment, why isn't `myObject.direction` just `null` like it would be with most other types?

Comment: @minseong It is indeed `null`, but you don't need to have a non-null value to access a static field. `LEFT` is a static field.

Comment: Am I right to take away that `Direction.LEFT.RIGHT.LEFT.RIGHT.RIGHT` is valid and is exactly the same as `Direction.RIGHT`?

Comment: @minseong Yes, because of how static fields work, but I suggest that you never write such a thing, because it is very confusing.

Comment: Actually I get the error `Cannot read property 'LEFT' of null`

Comment: @minseong Please show a [mcve]. Otherwise you can try one of the other answers. I recommend ernest_k's.

Comment: In my case I was getting the error because GraalVM doesn't let you access static properties on instances. I'll look into changing that setting and otherwise I will just have a method that uses Enum.valueOf. Your answer actually works in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you can't do that. You can't "refer to" or alias a type like that in Java.

What you're trying to do seems a lot like using constants. I have no idea why you'd want to do that, but here's a version using final properties in a third class:

```
public static class MyClass {
    public DirectionHolder direction = new DirectionHolder();

    public static class DirectionHolder {
        public final Direction LEFT = Direction.LEFT;
        public final Direction Right = Direction.RIGHT;
    }
}
```

This will make your `myObject.direction.LEFT == Direction.LEFT;` code compile and run, but it has limitations. Among others, `DirectionHolder` will need to be maintained so that it remains in sync with `Direction`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I alias an enum?

You cannot alias the entire enum, but you can alias each value individually, not that I would recommend it.

```java
public static final Direction LEFT = Direction.LEFT;
public static final Direction RIGHT = Direction.RIGHT;
```

Since `MyClass.LEFT` and `Direction.LEFT` both refer to the same object, the usual ability to use `==` with enums is still working, i.e. `MyClass.LEFT == Direction.LEFT` is true.